# Domains and Multiple Platforms Uploaded to Same Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, ionic-framework

I have both an Ionic and a Rails application. I'm currently wanting to push both apps onto the same EC2 instance. Ionic will act as a login section and several other pages. The rails application is intended to be a shopping cart and is only accessible when a user is logged in. I'm confused on a couple of points.

Am I right to believe both apps should be under different subdomains? Can I instead push both apps to two separate servers while still maintaining two separate subdomains? If two separate servers are used, can I expect sessions and localStorage to work across both applications? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are mixing up many things.

**Domains & Subdomains**

Let me explain that point with an example :
sub.example.com : first subdomain
other.example.com : second subdomain

Domains and subdomain are pointer to a server ip. Therefore, both example can point to the same EC2 instance.
The domain and subdomain shall therefore not enter into consideration into your analysis.

**Webserver & Session Management**

I'm not an expert and that point at all, but the magic is performed generaly here to share information & Sessions.
Common Webservers are Apache / Tomcat or even Jetty.
Some person use for session management REDIS too

**LocalStorage**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but localStorage can't be shared from one site to another.

> Your problem resides more into this question :
>
> What webserver am I using ?
>
> Or : How Tomcat7 manage sessions ?
>
> Or : Can I share session from different Webservers ?